# Passing Context to Interface Methods

Tags: go

Somewhat inspired by [this article](https://medium.com/@benbjohnson/structuring-applications-in-go-3b04be4ff091) last week, I'm toying with refactoring an application I have to more explicitly pass context (DB pools, session stores, etc) to my handlers.

However, one issue I'm having is that without a global templates map, the `ServeHTTP` method on my custom handler type (as to satisfy `http.Handler`) can no longer access the map to render a template.

I need to either retain the global `templates` variable, or re-define my custom handler type as a struct.

Is there a better way to achieve this?

**func.go**

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "log"
    "net/http"

    "html/template"

    "github.com/gorilla/sessions"
    "github.com/jmoiron/sqlx"
    "github.com/zenazn/goji/graceful"
    "github.com/zenazn/goji/web"
)

var templates map[string]*template.Template

type appContext struct {
    db    *sqlx.DB
    store *sessions.CookieStore
}

type appHandler func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) (int, error)

func (ah appHandler) ServeHTTP(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    // templates must be global for us to use it here
    status, err := ah(w, r)
    if err != nil {
        log.Printf("HTTP %d: %q", status, err)
        switch status {
        case http.StatusNotFound:
            // Would actually render a "http_404.tmpl" here...
            http.NotFound(w, r)
        case http.StatusInternalServerError:
            // Would actually render a "http_500.tmpl" here
            // (as above)
            http.Error(w, http.StatusText(status), status)
        default:
            // Would actually render a "http_error.tmpl" here
            // (as above)
            http.Error(w, http.StatusText(status), status)
        }
    }
}

func main() {
    // Both are 'nil' just for this example
    context := &appContext{db: nil, store: nil}

    r := web.New()
    r.Get("/", appHandler(context.IndexHandler))
    graceful.ListenAndServe(":8000", r)
}

func (app *appContext) IndexHandler(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) (int, error) {
    fmt.Fprintf(w, "db is %q and store is %q", app.db, app.store)
    return 200, nil
}
```

**struct.go**

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "log"
    "net/http"

    "html/template"

    "github.com/gorilla/sessions"
    "github.com/jmoiron/sqlx"
    "github.com/zenazn/goji/graceful"
    "github.com/zenazn/goji/web"
)

type appContext struct {
    db        *sqlx.DB
    store     *sessions.CookieStore
    templates map[string]*template.Template
}

// We need to define our custom handler type as a struct
type appHandler struct {
    handler func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) (int, error)
    c       *appContext
}

func (ah appHandler) ServeHTTP(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    status, err := ah.handler(w, r)
    if err != nil {
        log.Printf("HTTP %d: %q", status, err)
        switch status {
        case http.StatusNotFound:
            // Would actually render a "http_404.tmpl" here...
            http.NotFound(w, r)
        case http.StatusInternalServerError:
            // Would actually render a "http_500.tmpl" here
            // (as above)
            http.Error(w, http.StatusText(status), status)
        default:
            // Would actually render a "http_error.tmpl" here
            // (as above)
            http.Error(w, http.StatusText(status), status)
        }
    }
}

func main() {
    // Both are 'nil' just for this example
    context := &appContext{db: nil, store: nil}

    r := web.New()
    // A little ugly, but it works.
    r.Get("/", appHandler{context.IndexHandler, context})
    graceful.ListenAndServe(":8000", r)
}

func (app *appContext) IndexHandler(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) (int, error) {
    fmt.Fprintf(w, "db is %q and store is %q", app.db, app.store)
    return 200, nil
}
```

Is there a cleaner way to pass the `context` instance to `ServeHTTP`?

Note that `go build -gcflags=-m` shows that neither option appears to be worse in teams of heap allocation: the `&appContext` literal escapes to the heap (as expected) in both cases, although my interpretation is that the struct-based option does pass a second pointer (to `context`) on each request—**correct me if I'm wrong here** as I'd love to get a better understanding of this.

I'm not wholly convinced that globals are bad in package main (i.e. not a lib) provided they are safe to use in that manner (read only/mutexes/a pool), but I do like clarity having to explicitly pass context provides.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After some discussion with a couple of helpful Gophers on #go-nuts, the method above is about "as good as it gets" from what I can discern.

- The "con" with this method is that we pass a reference to our context struct *twice*: once as a pointer receiver in our method, and again as a struct member so `ServeHTTP` can access it as well.
- The "pro" is that we can extend our struct type to accept a request context struct if we wanted to do so (like [gocraft/web](https://github.com/gocraft/web/) does).

Note that we can't define our handlers as methods on `appHandler` i.e. `func (ah *appHandler) IndexHandler(...)` because we need to call the handler in `ServeHTTP` (i.e. `ah.h(w,r)`).

```
type appContext struct {
    db        *sqlx.DB
    store     *sessions.CookieStore
    templates map[string]*template.Template
}

type appHandler struct {
    handler func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) (int, error)
    *appContext // Embedded so we can just call app.db or app.store in our handlers.
}

// In main() ...
context := &appContext{db: nil, store: nil}
r.Get("/", appHandler{context.IndexHandler, context}) 
...
```

This is also, most importantly, fully compatible with `http.Handler` so we can still wrap our handler struct with generic middleware like so: `gzipHandler(appHandler{context.IndexHandler, context})`.

(I'm still open to other suggestions however!)

---

**Update**

Thanks to [this great reply on Reddit](http://www.reddit.com/r/golang/comments/2apjja/passing_context_to_interface_methods/cixpku8) I was able to find a better solution that didn't require passing two references to my `context` instance per-request.

We instead just create a struct that accepts an embedded context and our handler type, and we still satisfy the `http.Handler` interface thanks to `ServeHTTP`. Handlers are no longer methods on our `appContext` type but instead just accept it as a parameter, which leads to a slightly longer function signature but is still "obvious" and easy to read. If we were concerned about 'typing' we're breaking even because we no longer have a method receiver to worry about.

```
type appContext struct {
    db    *sqlx.DB
    store *sessions.CookieStore
    templates map[string]*template.Template

type appHandler struct {
    *appContext
    h func(a *appContext, w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) (int, error)
}

func (ah appHandler) ServeHTTP(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    // We can now access our context in here.
    status, err := ah.h(ah.appContext, w, r)
    log.Printf("Hello! DB: %v", ah.db)
    if err != nil {
        log.Printf("HTTP %d: %q", status, err)
        switch status {
        case http.StatusNotFound:
            // err := ah.renderTemplate(w, "http_404.tmpl", nil)
            http.NotFound(w, r)
        case http.StatusInternalServerError:
            // err := ah.renderTemplate(w, "http_500.tmpl", nil)
            http.Error(w, http.StatusText(status), status)
        default:
            // err := ah.renderTemplate(w, "http_error.tmpl", nil)
            http.Error(w, http.StatusText(status), status)
        }
    }
}

func main() {
    context := &appContext{
        db:    nil,
        store: nil,
        templates: nil,
    }

    r := web.New()
    // We pass a reference to context *once* per request, and it looks simpler
    r.Get("/", appHandler{context, IndexHandler})

    graceful.ListenAndServe(":8000", r)
}

func IndexHandler(a *appContext, w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) (int, error) {
    fmt.Fprintf(w, "db is %q and store is %q\n", a.db, a.store)
    return 200, nil
}
```

Answer (score 6):

I would use a closure and do something like this:

```
func IndexHandler(a *appContext) http.Handler {
    return http.HandlerFunc(func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *httpRequest) {
        // ... do stuff
        fmt.Fprintf(w, "db is %q and store is %q\n", a.db, a.store)
    })
}
```

And just use the returned `http.Handler`.

You'll just have to make sure your `appContext` is goroutine-safe.

Comment: Thanks. Normally I would lean on a closure for this since they're simple to implement, although a little repetitive. However I need to satisfy two interfaces: `http.Handler` *and* `web.Handler` (the former plus a request context tacked on) and can't achieve that with a closure.

Comment: You could implement your own type similar to [http.HandlerFunc](http://golang.org/pkg/net/http/#HandlerFunc) to satisfy all your interfaces.

Comment: Which is exactly what I've done (as my per my own answer) :) `appHandler` has a ServeHTTP method and a (not shown) ServeHTTPC method to satisfy both interfaces.